# Is it possible to create a user without internet access on Win 8 (no parental controls)

Tags: windows-8.1, internet-connection, restrictions

I want to create a user on a Windows 8 System that has no internet access. I do not want to monitor access or block some some sites / ports. I want the complete internet to be deactivated for said user.

Is that possible? If yes- how? Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to keep the local network in tact? What privileges does the user has (in terms of being able to undo it themselves if they have the knowledge)

Comment: Do you have access to creating a server or proxy in the way? Do you want other programs to have their way around by changing their own proxy settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. Create a standard user account then schedule a script that runs on logon of that user that uses [netsh](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738592%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) to delete the default gateway from the network adapter and another script to restore the correct default gateway setting at their logoff.

To delete default gateway:

```
route delete 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 <GATEWAY_IP>
```

To restore the default gateway:

```
route add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 <GATEWAY_IP>
```

Comment: I don't know if it's me, but the netsh syntax is very confusing...
I keep getting "Command not found" errors.

netsh set address name=Ethernet gateway=none ?

Comment: Answer updated with commands to delete and add routes, although I've provided ones using the `route` command.